# Statistics - reversed Bellcurve?

Tags: statistics

If i have a given dataset with an unknown probability p, can i make a graph to see how likely it is that p is a given percentage?

Small example:
10 tries

**unknown** p=50%

result: 6 "hits"

How likely is it that p is any specific percentage (like 49%) if we don't know it?

Is their some term for a graph showing the likelyhood of each percentage?

Edit: p is the probability to "hit" (whatever that means, call it tails if you want)

p is unknown to me, but obviously it has some value, which might deviate from the actual result value (in my example one could guess its 0.6, but its in reality 0.5)

My question is simply: how to graph/calculate the chance that a certain probability is the true one, if you just have a dataset and no clues (like "is this coin fair?")

In my example the graph should be looking something like this, but how do you make it properly?

[image]

Edit2: 10 tries is a really small samplesize, and i chose it to get my point across, but as it seems it was unclear. So to explain my example:

I throw a coin 10 times and get 6 tails. How high is the chance for a tail with this coin?

And now what i want to really know:

How high is the chance that the probability of a tails is 0.6?

How high is it for 0.5?

How high is it for $0<x<1$?

Comment: Seems a bit vague to me. Can you please be specific about how 6 hits in 10 tries gave p=50%. Seems binomial, yet you say bell (normal) curve. Are you using normal approximation to binomial with only $n = 10$ trials? Is $p$ the success (hit) probability?

Comment: @BruceET is it now clearer what I mean?

Comment: Sorry, not really. Once again, **"Can you please be specific about how 6 hits in 10 tries gave p=50%?"** That might help me (or someone else here) know what you're asking.

Comment: @BruceET A fair coin has 50%, but as you know 10 tries is a small samplesize. So 6 tails is not really a crazy result. But we don't know if the coin isn't rigged. So my question is how high is the probability that p=0.6 is actually right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical problem in Bayesian inference.  We usually solve it by assuming a uniform prior.  That is, we assume that before we have any information to go off of, the parameter for the binomial distribution is equally likely to be anywhere from 0 to 1.  Bayseian inference says that the posterior distribution of the parameter (the graph you are looking for) is proportional to the prior distribution multiplied by the likelihood function.  If $x$ is the observed data, $g$ is the probability distribution for the parameter, and $f$ is the likelihood function:
$$g(p|x)\propto g(p)\cdot f(x|p)$$
In our case $g(p)=1$ and $f(x|p)$ is the probability of observing $x$ hits given $p$.
$$f(x|p)=\binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$$
So,
$$g(p|x)\propto\binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$$
Which, viewed as a distribution for $p$, is recognizable as a $beta(a,b)$ distribution with $a=x+1$ and $b=n-x+1$.
Since this is a proper distribution (the integral over the entire real line is one, etc.) we know that the graph you are trying to construct is that of a beta distribution with parameter $a=6+1$ and $b=10-6+1$.

Comment: I believe the point "the integral has to be 1" would have helped me a lot to ask my question hehe. Big thanks for your answer :)